# How to insert value in sorted array and keep array sorted?

Tags: javascript, arrays

What is the best way to insert value in an array and keep the array sorted?

for example here is an array

```
const arr = [1, 4, 23, 45];
```

I can add a new value using method push or splice, for example 16, and I'll get modified array:

```
[1, 4, 23, 45, 16]
```

But I need to keep array sorted:

```
[1, 4, 16, 23, 45]
```

What is the better way to keep array sorted? Should I sort every time when add a new value, or detect necessary index for inserting a new value?

Comment: Identifying the position to insert would be less computationally complex, and trivial

Comment: Detecting the index and putting a value there is `O(n)`, while sorting is usually `O(n*log(n))`. Therefore insert at index is better.

Comment: It really depends on the size of you array. If it's relativement small, it really won't make a difference. If not, do as others have suggested. Code simplicity/readability is often more important than pure performance.

Answer (score 4):

Just look at the complexities:

- SORTING: O(nlogn) in the best scenario
- INDEX INSERT: O(n) in the *worst scenario*
- SORTING SMART: O(n) in the best scenario, using algorithms like insertionSort, that work very well when the array is almost already sorted
- BINARY INSERTION: O(logn) **this is the preferred way**

```js
function  binaryInsertion(arr, element) {
    return binaryHelper(arr, element, 0, arr.length - 1);
}

function binaryHelper(arr, element, lBound, uBound) {
    if (uBound - lBound === 1) {
        // binary search ends, we need to insert the element around here       
        if (element < arr[lBound]) arr.splice(lBound, 0, element);
        else if (element > arr[uBound]) arr.splice(uBound+1, 0, element);
        else arr.splice(uBound, 0, element);
    } else {       
        // we look for the middle point
        const midPoint = Math.floor((uBound - lBound) / 2) + lBound;
        // depending on the value in the middle, we repeat the operation only on one slice of the array, halving it each time
        element < arr[midPoint]
            ? binaryHelper(arr, element, lBound, midPoint)
            : binaryHelper(arr, element, midPoint, uBound);
    }
}

console.log("even array test");
var array = [1,3,4,5,9];
binaryInsertion(array, 2);
console.log(array);

console.log("odd array test");
var array = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15];
binaryInsertion(array, 10);
console.log(array);

console.log("beginning and end test");
var array = [2,3,4,5,9];
binaryInsertion(array, 0);
binaryInsertion(array, 10);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Smart detection should be lower than `O(n)` - it's `O(log(n))` for a sorted array, using binary chop to find the correct index.

Comment: @VLAZ you're right! Thanks for pointing that out, I completely forgot about it. I added it to the answer and will add some code for it (the question is closed but maybe it'll still help some lost soul).

Comment: Lost soul here, this code results in a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.` if the array starts with fewer than 2 elements. This may not be elegant but it fixes the issue:
```function  binaryInsertion(arr, element) {  
 if (arr.length==0) return arr.push(element);  
 if (arr.length==1) return element < arr[0] ? arr.unshift(element) : arr.push(element);  
    return binaryHelper(arr, element, 0, arr.length - 1);  
}``` (Sorry, no code blocks in comments.)